# What is wrong with the following Click event?

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub btnRunDemo_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, By Val e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnRunDemo.Click

  Dim count As Integer = 0

  Do While count > 10
      1stOutput.Items.Add("Hello")
      count += 1

  Loop
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: We'll need a bit more information such as a) What you expect it to do and b) what it actually does. Looking at the method there's nothing wrong with it but the item will never get added to the list as count is always less than 10

Comment: in the way you have it right now, `count` is never `> 10`

Comment: You probably want `Do While count < 10`

Answer (score 2):

Having `While>10` won't ever go in there if the `count` is set to `0`. You need to use `Until`.

`While` here means 'As long as count is greater than 10 do the loop'. But you are setting count to 0, so it is not greater than 10 so it will not enter the loop.

```
Private Sub btnRunDemo_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, By Val e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnRunDemo.Click

  Dim count As Integer = 0

  Do Until count > 10
      1stOutput.Items.Add("Hello")
      count += 1

  Loop
End Sub
```